# Artifact extractor from java source

Tags: java, c++, parsing

Do you know of a C++ library (open source, or free for non-commercial use) that can parse Java source codes, for example from a jar file or defined classpath? I want to extract classes, class members, methods, method calls and relations between these artifacts.

I've spent all day googling for a solution. Either I'm blind, or can't read! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get source codes from a *jar* file, since that is really a set of (binary) class files.  Assuming you means the source codes that might have been used to produce a jar file, then there's a decent answer.

If you want an open source solution, you can try [ANTLR](http://antlr.org), which has a [Java 1.5 grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1152141644268/Java.g) and AFAIK will build AST.  From that you can "extract" the trees for the items you want, or at least the line numbers for the subtree of interest; from there, you can extract the code you want.

I believe ANTLR can be configured to produce a C++-based parser.

To capture *relations* between these, you need full name and type resolution, so you know which definition an identifier actually references.  For this, ANTLR being just a parser won't do the trick; you need to live a [Life After Parsing](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html).

An alternative might be the Java compiler; it offers some kind of API.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of decompilers available for Java. These aren't based on C++ necessarily, but they can convert Java classes and libraries back into source.

Examples: [JD Core](http://jd.benow.ca/), DJ Java Decompiler. [more](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20decompiler&es_th=1)